# How to apply calculation to column of text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to apply a calculation to every value of every column in my csv file and replacing the old values with these new calculated values.

```
#temp_list is a list of lists. Eg. [['1.3','2.2','1.6'],['1.2','4.5','2.3']]
for row in temp_list:
    minimum = min(row) #find minimum value of values in column 2
    y = every value in the 2nd column - minimum

    #for every value in the 2nd column, apply y calculation to it and replace original values with these values
    row[1] = float(row[1])
```

I understand that if I did

```
row[1] = float(row[1]) * 3
```

for example, I would get each value in column 2 (index 1) to be multiplied by 3. How would I do that for my y calculation written above?

Comment: `minimum = min(row) #find minimum value of values in column 2` - this line doesn't do what the comment says.

Comment: What do you mean by `y = every value in the 2nd column - minimum`? Could you provide an example of your expected output?

Comment: @goodvibration I've tried multiple things such as min(row[1]) and it's not doing what I need it to do.

Comment: @tfw Basically I need every value in the 2nd column. In this case 2.2 and 4.5 (which is index 1) - minimum value of each list (1.3 and 1.2 respectively). So using my calculation y, it becomes 2.2-1.3 and 4.5-1.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to transpose the list of lists, convert the sequence to a list and then use `[1]` to get the values in the second row (originally second column), so that you can use the `min` function with `float` as a key function to get minimum of the values based on their values in floating point:

```
min(list(zip(*temp_list))[1], key=float)
```

This returns: `2.2`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think this is what you wanted.
Since your lists are of strings, there's a bit of casting back and forth between `Decimal` and `string`

```py
from decimal import Decimal
temp_list = [['1.3','2.2','1.6'],['1.2','4.5','2.3']]

for x in temp_list:
  x[1] = str(Decimal(x[1]) - min(Decimal(y) for y in x))

print(temp_list)
# [['1.3', '0.9', '1.6'], ['1.2', '3.3', '2.3']]
```